# Hibernate: ManyToOne relation inside composite key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have the following database(mysql) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE hq_type (
  id_hq_type INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (id_hq_type)
);

CREATE TABLE hq (
  year INTEGER NOT NULL,
  id_hq_type INTEGER NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY (year,id_hq_type),
  ....
  CONSTRAINT fk_hq_hq_type FOREIGN KEY (id_hq_type) REFERENCES hq_type (id_hq_type)
);
```

I am trying this code to represent the composite key and the ManyToOne relation in the hq table without success:

```
class IdClass implements Serializable {
        private Integer year;
        private Integer idHqType;

        ....
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hq")
@IdClass(IdClass.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Hq implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "year", nullable = false)
    private Integer year;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_hq_type")
    private Tipo idHqType;

    .......
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hq_type")
public class Tipo implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_hq_type")
    private Integer idHqType;
```

How can I represent that table correctly?

Comment: First of all, you have a weird foreign key constraint definition: `CONSTRAINT fk_hq_city FOREIGN KEY (hq)` - why is it `hq` in brackets, which is the name of the table actually. Secondly, please, add how do define you field which references city in `HqPK` (it's definitely not a `year` field, i suppose).

Comment: I have edited my question. It is the year column and the id_hq_type column where my problem is: The composite primary key and the foreign key

Comment: Also, please add what you have in `Tipo` class